# When only tags are edited the edit summary is mandatory, but text is discarded on save?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, edits

Last week the [retag] button was removed and its functionality was merged with a smart [edit] button. This smart feature decides itself what has been edited and applies tag edits immediately or puts edit into edit queue if user has enough reputation for former but not for the latter.

I noticed however that [Save Edits] button requires the edit summary field to be at least 10 characters long. However, if you fill in those 10 characters your text is then replaced with generic 'edited tags'.

This behavior is counter-intuitive. If the user enters edit summary it should be kept. If the summary is always filled with generic description, then user should be able to save edits without filling in "Edit Summary" text.

Is this a bug, or does it behave as intended?

Comment: @Mat I checked that short one tag edit (3 characters long) do not trigger "Edits must be at least 6 characters..." message.

Comment: I might have misread your post, sorry. Are you saying you _always_ need to fill in the edit summary field when only retagging?

Comment: @Mat Yes, I checked it twice after posting the question here. Each time I see this "10 characters" message and each time I enter text (even not mentioning word 'tag' or the name of the tag I used in case if the smart feature decides that description is in fact worthless) it is always replaced with 'edited tags'.

Comment: Ok, does sound like bug/unintended "feature" :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retag as a separate privilege [has been removed.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182586/do-we-still-need-the-retag-privilege)

Tag-only suggested edits still require an edit summary to be provided, and the summary entered will appear with the final revision when the edit is approved.

Comment: "Mission Retag" on the way. :)

Comment: Aha, I've noticed recently that my tag edits are no longer auto-approved, but was not sure if this a bug or a feature. So this is a feature.